# Pocketing last c/m along with striker

Tags: carrom

What happens if I pocket my last c/m along with striker?
Opponent's **n** C/m are still on board.

- Will I win with minimum **n** points?
- Will it be a double-due?
- Will I lose the game?

Answer (score -1):

Neither you won nor lose the game, keep the Queen on board and pocket along with your C/m